# React- Pass event to inner child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, eventhandler

I have an element and a child element, both have an event handler, however, the parent handler seems to block the child handler.
I have tried to use https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events.
sadly its didn't work or I didn't use it correctly.

Where is some of my code:
classes:
`Matrix` and `Tile`
the Matrix render function contains:

```
<element onMouseDown={this._onPressDown} onMouseUp={this._onPressUp}><Matrix/></element>
```

`Matrix` include the `Tile` object as `NxN` matrix as following:

```
[[<Tile/>,<Tile/>],[<Tile/>,<Tile/>]]
```

the Tile render functioncontains:

```
<div onClick={this._onClick} onMouseEnter={this._onEnter}><Matrix/></div>
```

The child (tile) function `_onClicked` is not beening called.

Edit:

```
  buildMatrix(){
    let [tileWidth,tileHeight] = this.calculateTileSize();
    this.reBuildMatrix = !this.reBuildMatrix;
    return  (<element onMouseDown={this._onPressDown} onMouseUp={this._onPressUp} stopPropagation>
                <table className='matrix' key={this.reBuildMatrix}>{   
                            this.state.tileMatrixMap.map((rowItem,row)=>(
                                <tr>
                                    {
                                        rowItem.map((tile,col)=>(
                                        <th><Tile 
                                            width={tileWidth}
                                            height={tileHeight} 
                                            isWall={tile.isWall}
                                            isPath={tile.isPath}
                                            onClick={tile.onClick}
                                            position= {[row,col]}
                                            backgroundColor={tile.isWall?this.wallColor:(tile.isPath? this.pathColor:this.backgroundColor)}
                                        /></th>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                    </table>
            </element>);
```

When this line is disabled `this.reBuildMatrix = !this.reBuildMatrix;`
the code work as expexted, how ever if I enable the line the function is not called

Comment: React components do not stop propagation, so  by default it should work as you want it to work. Can you create a small example on codepen (or similar) to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Here is the code sand, the code is exactly the same. However, it's run on their preview platform and not on mine. Furthermore, when I deploy it to their server the problem accrues. Code: https://codesandbox.io/live/lb2p1oc
Site:https://csb-5ei2g.netlify.app/

Comment: you can stop event propagation in react by using .stopPropagation() method on the event. you can stop the propagation of both the component parent and child. you need to add this method to the function of that event.

Comment: The new edit includes the problem line

Comment: So, you're destroying the matrix before the event has a chance to fire?

Comment: I'm changing the key of the matrix so the matrix will update when I setState

Comment: I does not update, it gets unmounted, and a completely new one is created - look at the DOM in dev tools it changes on every click. When state changes React updates components anyways, there is no need to change DOM structure.

Comment: I've don't that, however, the state take a while to update

Comment: It should update immediately. Maybe make a small example of your code to demonstrate what is happening vs what you expect.

Comment: I've made a mistake, I deliver a new prop to the object however I didn't set the state, therefore the state hasn't changed, Thanks all for the help!